# Vertical Swipe Recognizer Sencha touch 2 enabling

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch-2, swipe

I am currently developing an application with the Sencha Touch 2 mobile.
I have to handle a swipe down event in the application on particular control but by default the VerticalSwipe Recognizer is disabled.

Can anyone tell me how to enable it as i am not able to find much of the relevant information on this.
I have already checked a few posts on sencha that describes to use the Ext.setup method. But I am using a MVC architecture so I only have Ext.application() available to me.

I have gone through it somewhere, that it can be done using the eventPublishers in Ext.application().

Comment: should the swipe be attached to a particular element/component or to any/all the app?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial:
http://www.chrisrossi.com/2011/03/16/how-to-add-updown-swipe-functionality-to-sencha-touch/